# JSON Parsing Exception

Tags: json.net

```
Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(Of T)(JsonData)
```

The above line throws exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

when JsonData is

```
{"access_token":"ya29.ygAuJKvaVXdJm_QYUgz4oEqN6sjU6W4QwpPsI93RfH-ScW9U1olhgz9S924g7TV5WqDE_Vzfvqx6YQ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"refresh_token":null,"Issued":"11/25/2014 6:59:11 PM"}
```

but works ok wnen JsonData is

```
{"access_token":null,"token_type":null,"expires_in":null,"refresh_token":null,"Issued":"01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM"}
```

Can't figure out why. Any pointers?

Comment: What is the definition of `T` in your deserialization code above?  In other words, what class are you trying to deserialize to?

Comment: A simple class with get/set only to hold values such as access_token, token_type, etc.

Comment: FYI, your JSON deserializes just fine using the regular version of Json.Net.  Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xBfcMu.  So, either there's something different in Google's embedded version, or else there's something in your code that is blanking out or changing the JsonData string before you call Deserialize.